# Округление числа до ближайшего целого

Tags: python, числа

По правилам числа округляются до ближайшего целого числа,а если дробная часть числа равна `0.5`, то число округляется вверх.

Решил таким способом, получил `100/100`, но хотел бы избавиться от числа `1000000`, так как при вводе числа x, `4999999` округляет вверх:

```
from math import *
x = float(input())
a = floor(x)
b = x - a
if (int(round(b, 1000000)*100)) < 50:
    print(int(x))
elif (int(round(b, 1000000)*100)) == 50 or (int(round(b, 2)*100)) > 50:
    print(ceil(x))
```

Comment: непонятно в чем проблема

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно округлять числа в определенную сторону то используйте следующие функции

А если вам нужно при определенном остатке округлять число в ту или иную сторону, то можете попробовать использовать остаток от деления(%) двух чисел и сравнивать уже по нему

`math.ceil()` – округление чисел в большую сторону

`math.floor()` – округление чисел в меньшую сторону

`math.trunc()` – отбрасывание дробной части

Answer (score 0):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer)

```
def proper_round(num, dec=0):
    num = str(num)[:str(num).index('.')+dec+2]
    if num[-1]>='5':
        return float(num[:-2-(not dec)]+str(int(num[-2-(not dec)])+1))
    return float(num[:-1])
```